# pkg-config pointing to 1.10 version instead of 1.14

Tags: installation, centos, gstreamer

I am trying to install gstreamer 1.14.4 at a different location than `/usr` or `/usr/local`.

**What I am doing:**
I have downloaded the following packages:
    [gstreamer-1.14.4.tar.xz](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer/)
    [gst-plugins-base-1.14.4.tar.xz](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-base/)
    [gst-plugins-good-1.14.4.tar.xz](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/)
    [gst-plugins-bad-1.14.4.tar.xz](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/)
    [gst-plugins-ugly-1.14.4.tar.xz](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-ugly/)

Now I trying to install them in the same order as given above.

**Installing gstreamer-1.14.4.tar.xz**
Extract the tarball
`./configure --prefix=/path/to/xyz`
`make`
`make install`

*This creates `gst-launch-1.0`, `gst-inspect-1.0`, `gst-stats-1.0` and `gst-typefind-1.0` in **/path/to/xyz/`bin`**. And similarly required `*.so` are created in **/path/to/xyz/`lib`** and **/path/to/xyz/`lib/gstreamer-1.0/`***

Then I put this bin path in env variable PATH as `export PATH=/path/to/xyz/bin:$PATH`

**Installing gst-plugins-base-1.14.4.tar.xz**
Extract the tarball
`./configure --prefix=/path/to/xyz`

It gives me error:

```
checking for GST... no
configure: No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found
configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.14.4 (GStreamer) found
```

**EDIT 1:**
The latest version of gstreamer package in centOS repository is 1.10.4. After installing that with `yum install gstreamer-1.0`, Now I am getting this following error

```
checking for GST... no
configure: Requested 'gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.14.4' but version of GStreamer is 1.10.4
configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.14.4 (GStreamer) found
```

So that means earlier pkg-config wasn't able to find gstreamer, and now it does but pointing to 1.10 version instead of 1.14. Is there a way around this?

Comment: you need to set --libdir=<path> while compiling plugins.

Comment: you mean `./configure --prefix=/path/to/xyz --libdir=/path/to/xyz/lib` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` if your package is not in default location.

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

See this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable)